# What is struct hstate in hugetlb.c?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, huge-pages

In `hugetlb_init_hstates()`, it has this:

```
for_each_hstate(h) { 
  if(h->order < MAX_ORDER) {
    hugetlb_hstate_alloc_pages(h);
  }
}
```

Does every `hstate` mean one hugepage?

Answer (score 2):

Each hstate is one huge-page **pool** for a certain unit size and of a certain NUMA node. Each hstate is represented by one `/sys/devices/system/node/node<ID>/hugepages/hugepages-<size>/` directory in `sysfs`. On normal desktops you'd usually find only one global hstate of 2MB pages and another one for 1GB pages, through the latter one is not supported on all architectures.